# Vue dynamic component renders twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-dynamic-components

I'm rendering dynamic components inside a dashboard parent item. If there's a component, it renders. If there's not, well... then it doesn't. The problem is that my only dynamic component for now is being rendered twice.

I've tried rendering conditionally, etc, but nothing works.

I'm going to post some code here but you I'm working on a Sandbox, so maybe that's better.

No console errors, just a couple warnings. **Any ideas?**

Comment: what are items?

Comment: just the ones defined above

Comment: so you have 2 items and you are using v-for, so it should render twice. can you send a screenshot of what is getting rendered

Comment: The one that is being rendered twice is one of them. Can you access the sandbox linked above?

Comment: Added the screenshot

Comment: well it renders one item, but 2 images!!

Comment: The component itself is for now just an image, if I add a little text, for example, it also renders twice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/01m594v78l

You have two `<slot></slot>` tags in `DashboardItem.vue`. Remove one ;)

Comment: They were hidden! Thank you!